# How to Remove Swipe Previous / Next Post in Blogger

Tags: blogger

In Blogger / Blogspot, mobile templates come with a swipe feature that you can't apparently disable and that will go to the previous/next post if you swipe left or right.

This is nice and all, but my post has a table and the swipe feature won't allow me to scroll horizontally. Which kinda sucks.

Is there a way to disable scrolling?

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answer by *OdraEncoded* above, together with the suggestion from *Blog Matheus Produções* in [Blogger Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/8hNsCLpEn6U;context-place=forum/blogger), I think the final code below should be limiting the disabling of id=main events to the posts in mobile pages.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>

    <script>
      // hackiest thing in the universe so disable the stupid swiping from blogger
      document.getElementById('main').addEventListener = function() {}
    </script>

  </b:if>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Blogger engine will inject scripts at the end of the template whether you want it or not in the mobile version. Since God only knows how and when they are injected and if there is a way to prevent that, I guess it's too difficult to do prevent the scripts for loading entirely. But you can make them do nothing with this one simple hack.

Just add the following lines before `</body>` in the template.

```
<script>
    // hackiest thing in the universe so disable the stupid swiping from blogger
    document.getElementById('main').addEventListener = function() {}
</script>
```

On the minus side, you can't add any events at all to the `id=main` `div`. On the plus side, the swiping is gone because the Blogger script can't add the `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events either. Hooray!